# XNA: avoid mouse cursor texture scaling according to transform matrix

Tags: c#, xna

I need to draw the mouse cursor in the right world position, so I used this code:

```
Matrix inverseViewMatrix = Matrix.Invert(camera.GetViewMatrix(graphics.GraphicsDevice));
mousePos.X -= cursorTex.Width / 2;
mousePos.Y -= cursorTex.Height / 2;
Vector2 worldMousePosition = Vector2.Transform(mousePos, inverseViewMatrix);
spriteBatch.Draw(cursorTex, worldMousePosition, Color.White);
```

This actually works, but when I zoom out the camera I got the mouse cursor scaled.

Is there a way to avoid this? I wish to keep the original cursor texture dimension (32 x 32) also when I zoom out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is to draw the mouse cursor in a separate spritebatch, removing the scale.

> ```
> SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, camera.GetViewMatrix(graphics.GraphicsDevice));
> //Regular Draw Code
> SpriteBatch.End();
>
> SpriteBatch.Begin();
> //Mouse Cursor Draw Code
> SpriteBatch.End();
> ```

**EDIT**

Another option would be to scale your texture manually, based on the current camera zoom level.  You basically just adjust the scale of your cursor texture based on that zoom level.

In the same draw call as all your other stuff, you could do:

```
float scale = 1 / camera.Scale;    //untested
Helper.SpriteBatch.Draw(cursorTex, worldMousePosition, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1);
```

Assuming your camera keeps track of the current world scale.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to draw the mouse cursor in another SpriteBatch.Begin() as you suggest; the cursor now has the right dimension, but its position is pretty "busted".. It does not follows the real position of the mouse.

Comment: In that case, you could also manually scale your sprite accordingly.  I will update my answer.

Comment: It works! float scale = 1 / camera.Zoom; 
spriteBatch.Draw(cursorTex, worldMousePosition, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 1); //That's the code I used

Comment: Perfect.  I mistakenly multiplied instead of divided ;)